# Joint distribution with no density

Tags: probability

I'm trying to find random variables (from the same probability space) $X$ and $Y$ that each have densities but $(X,Y)$ does not.

Comment: See question 1289316.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do trivial examples count? Let $X$ have a density and define $Y:=X$. Then $(X,Y)$ has its mass concentrated on the line $y=x$ (a set of measure zero), so it cannot have a density on $R^2$.

Comment: thanks! may I ask how you thought up of this?

Comment: It's one of the standard counterexamples that you reach for. Along the same lines, try $Y=-X$ if you're trying to disprove an assertion about $X+Y$.